# Session management in emacs using Desktop library

Tags: emacs

For session management with emacs, I appended the following lines to my .emacs file

```
(load "desktop")
(desktop-load-default)
(desktop-read)
```

I was able to save the session using `M-x desktop-save`. But after exiting emacs, I am unable to recover the earlier saved session. I did start emacs in the same directory as that during "desktop-save"

Please let me know if I am missing anything or not correct in my efforts

Thanks
-- Harish

Answer (score 4):

Chapter 51 'Saving Emacs Sessions' of my Emacs manual (using a Emacs 23 snapshot)  has this

> You can save the desktop manually
>   with the command `M-x desktop-save'. 
>   You can also enable automatic saving
>   of the desktop when you exit Emacs,
>   and automatic restoration of the last
>   saved desktop when Emacs starts: use
>   the Customization buffer (*note Easy
>   Customization::) to set`
>   desktop-save-mode' to `t' for future
>   sessions, or add this line in your`
>   ~/.emacs' file:
>
> ```
>  (desktop-save-mode 1)
> ```

which is different from what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me (emacs 21.3.1):

```
(load "desktop")

(setq desktop-save-mode 1)

(desktop-load-default)
(desktop-read)
```

The desktop-save-mode line is only needed if you want to save desktop automatically on exit (i.e. without bothering to type `M-x deskstop-save`).

The only difference is that I put those lines at the beginning of the .emacs file but I doubt that's a problem.