# Can emacs sessions (open buffers) be restored on a restart

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore Emacs Session/Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703743/restore-emacs-session-desktop)

I am using emacs for development. And there may be many buffers open. Is there a way that I can save the state when I close emacs. So that when emacs is again opened it restores the different windows?

I am looking at what browsers are able to do for restoring a previous browsing session.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you don't ever "close" your Emacs. That's not meant to be a joke. The general style of working is to keep an Emacs running all the time and to just open new buffers in there using `emacsclient`. This is different from the vim style where vim is continuously opened and closed.

However, your question is an old one which has been asked by a lot of people and a lot of solutions have been proposed and coded up. There's a [list of them](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement) on emacswiki. You can pick one that works for you.